# Android SIP - failed to get invite signals

Tags: sip, voip

I am developing mVoIP application with SIP.

Currently, I've succeeded to send RINGING(180) signal on VoIP App (CSIPSimple). However, I failed to get Invite Signal from other VoIP Application.

My server logs show messages that is "Not Found" or "Request Timeout". I am assuming that there is a problem on "Contact, From, To or Via" in the header codes.

```
U 14.63.12.134:45629 -> 10.7.21.4:5060
  REGISTER sip:SIPDOMAIN.COM SIP/2.0..Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.0.28:45629;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjLGwYUJ4BzKL.SLqD89CpM5FFa67q8KAq..Max-Forwards: 70..From: "300" <sip:hjw@gpon.co.kr>;tag=mDOC8V0pWQNJeJ5-djP-6HoBOvD7hJTG..To: "300" <sip:hjw@SIPDOMAIN.COM>..Call-ID: OF5L5dsVBJ6dAuq.gKKqHw3S.xUIo1P8..CSeq: 33263 REGISTER..User-Agent: CSipSimple_ace-10/r2272..Contact: "300" <sip:hjw@192.168.0.28:45629;ob>..Expires: 900..Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY,REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS..Content-Length:  0....
```

Here are my questions.

1. Which IP address should I use when a user register and send the information(Via, Contact, To, From) to SIP server?  (Private IP or Public IP?)
2. Which "Port number" should I use when a user register? Do I have to open a port for NAT?
3. IS there any Routing Path config file that I should fix?
4. Why should I send "KeepAlive" Signal?

It's been a week to solve these problems, but I failed.
If you know any websites or documents that I have to read, please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Which IP address should I use when a user register and send the
>   information(Via, Contact, To, From) to SIP server? (Private IP or
>   Public IP?)

A normal/good server should be able to handle also private IP.
Using a public address has its benefits, but you should focus on this topic only later.

> Which "Port number" should I use when a user register? Do I have to
>   open a port for NAT?

Same as above. Just use the local IP:port

> Is there any Routing Path config file that I should fix?

There should be no such file (routing path is calculated automatically by the SIP client)

> Why should I send "KeepAlive" Signal?

You either have to reregister or send a keep alive message in around every minute, otherwise the NAT will timeout and you will not receive incoming message (incoming call or chat).